# Response image src in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, excel

I return HTML content and display in excel file in ASP.NET MVC.

My question is about img source.Img source does not work.

**My Code:**

```
public ActionResult ExportData()
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xls;");
    var stringWrite = new StringWriter();
    var htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

    var headerTable = @"<Table><tr><td><img src=""‪C:\Users\xx\Desktop\Export\Export\Images\orderedList0.png"" \></td></tr></Table>";

    Response.Write(headerTable);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();

    return RedirectToAction("StudentDetails");
}
```

Above code exports excell file without problem. I only have problem about displaying image. Image can not appear exactly. There is a problem about img source.

What is the correct way for img src for my code?

Comment: Always use relative url as much as possible as it saves you the hassle of changing lines while deploying.Use something like Fiddler to check the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind the path to the image you are embedding into Excel is an absolute path which MUST EXIST on the client's machine at that exact path.

I assume you get an image placeholder within the workbook? If so, it's a path problem. You will have to make sure the path points correctly to a file which exists at that exact path on that exact machine.

A much better idea would be to alter the src tag to be relative as Ash suggested and host the image from your webserver

```
var headerTable = @"<Table><tr><td><img src=""fullyqualifiedurltoimagefileonserver.png"" \></td></tr></Table>";
```

If you are 100% certain on the image path you may be facing an Excel security limitation.